# Problem in filling UITableViewCell from Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have a problem after the data being fetched from Core Data. I filled a TableView from the fetched data but the TableView shows the following data in it

(entity: Fortune; id: 0x6549c40  ; data: )

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Below is the code I used to fill TableViewCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];

Fortune *info = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
  cell.textLabel.text = info.description;


return cell;
```

}

Where Fortnue is my Managed Object Class and description is the column of type NSString.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[object description];` is a default method returning the description of the instance, memory address etc. You should not use the name 'description' for any of your properties of an `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: ok i changed the description to fortuneName. Now it gives the following error

The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store.

Comment: You will need to delete the installed app, if you change a model WITHOUT using the in-built versioning you will get the error you are describing.

Comment: hmm ok let me try this then will get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Simon Lee: Still getting the same problem sir. I deleted the app and then it works fine but the original problem for what i posted the question is back now. Again showing this in UITableViewCell '(entity: Fortune; id: 0x6549c40 ; data: )'

Comment: And you changed... cell.textLabel.text = info.description; to cell.textLabel.text = info.fortuneName; ??

Comment: Yes I did. I figured it out, i just clean the build and then ran it again and it worked perfectly. Thanks Sir for your help :)